# Difference between constructor and initializer

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a difference in C++ between copy initialization and direct initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051379/is-there-a-difference-in-c-between-copy-initialization-and-direct-initializati)
>   [What's the difference between explicit and implicit assignment in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057859/whats-the-difference-between-explicit-and-implicit-assignment-in-c)

Simple as that. What is the difference between

```
std::string a("abc");
```

and

```
std::string a = "abc";
```

Comment: Direct initialization vs. copy initialization. You can look it up based on those terms.