# OpemMP Explicit task vs implicit task.

Tags: task, openmp

What is the different between them in terms of use?
How can I tell this is an explicit task or implicit task?

If I would to instrument the run-time library of the task implementation, can I get different information about implicit and explicit task?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between explicit and implicit assignment in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057859/whats-the-difference-between-explicit-and-implicit-assignment-in-c)

Comment: I don't see the duplicatiness of this question, not of the one that @TahTatsumoto points to anyhow.

Comment: I think that section 5.1 of https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/820-7883/6nj43o69j/index.html answers OP's question.  I'm not sure there's anything to be gained by rehashing it.  I'm also not sure that later versions of the standard explain the difference quite as clearly.

Comment: Explicit tasks are created explicitly using the OpenMP `task` construct.